# Why is enum not a constant expression?

Tags: java, enums

Below is the code I was experimenting with:

```
public enum PagesEnum {
    PAGE1 {
        public static final SectionsEnum SECTION_A = SectionsEnum.SECTION_A;
        public static final SectionsEnum SECTION_B = SectionsEnum.SECTION_B;
    },

    PAGE2 {
        public static final SectionsEnum SECTION_C = SectionsEnum.SECTION_C;
        public static final SectionsEnum SECTION_D = SectionsEnum.SECTION_D;
    }
}

public enum SectionsEnum {

    SECTION_A,
    SECTION_B,
    SECTION_C,
    SECTION_D
}
```

(The goal of experiments is to get a syntax like `PAGE1.SECTION_A`, but that's not the focus of this question.)

I am getting the following compiler error in Eclipse:

> The field `SECTION_A` cannot be declared static in a non-static inner type, unless initialized with a constant expression

Now I'm a bit puzzled. `SECTION_A` is initialized with the enum `SectionsEnum.SECTION_A` - why isn't enum a constant expression? I've checked the JLS, enums indeed are not listen in [Constant Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28).

I wonder, why is that so.

Comment: Is the `PagesEnum` sub type created by `PAGE1{}` static? Maybe that's the part that gives you trouble: "...in a non-static inner type...".

Comment: @MalteHartwig I'm OK with `PAGE1{}` to be considered "non-static inner type". But what I don't get is why enum value is not a "constant expression". From my point of view there are few things in Java more constant than an enum value.

Comment: Yes, now that you repeat it this way... But anyway, I don't think it would work as you indend: `SECTION_X` will be a constant of an anonymous sub class of `PagesEnum`. Hence, you can never access them for lack of a class name to prefix them. If I remove the static modifier, Eclipse gives me this warning: "The value of the field new MyClass.PagesEnum(){}.SECTION_A is not used". That is the class defining the constants... not accessible by you, as it's anonymous.

Comment: @watchme Well, "constant variables" actually are listed in "constant expressions".

Comment: @MalteHartwig You are correct, this experiment will most probably fail. I'm fine with this, but it's not in scope of my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want understand then: that because `Java` load classes dynamically and `enum` is class too. So it should be resolved in run-time for initialization.

If you want formal reason: constant expression definition in [JLS 15.28](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28)

Comment: I know the formal reason, I was wondering why is it so. I guess you're right, must have something to do with how constant expressions are processed by the compiler.

Comment: For `java` runtime type of this variable is reference, you can't store value in `class` file, only code that will initialize it. So it is not compiler, but more `class` file format issue.